# Zoo of sigmoid integrals (computational convenience)

Tags: continuity, special-functions

In many areas in computational science (e.g. neural networks, fuzzy logic ... ) there is special interest in function [like sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGjl-t%28x%29.svg) ( erf, arctan, tanh ... ) which are kind of *blured* version of Heaviside step function, and it's derivative in shape of smooth peak ( Gaussian, Lorenz ... ).

I'm interested also in it's integral: Smooth monotoneously growing function which has smooth transition from $f'(x<<0) \approx 0$ to $f'(x>>0)\approx1$

**one of such function is**:
 $f(x) = (x + \sqrt{1+x^2})/2$

I would like some function of similar character which is **fast to evaluate numericaly on computer**.

- This means that it preferably should not use any transcedental
  functions like $\sqrt , \log, \exp, \sin, \sinh ... $.
- It should be preferably also as smooth as possible ( it should not contain terms like $|x|$ or `if () then {} else {}` )
- It would be also nice, that not only the function $f(x)$, but also it's first and second derivative ( $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ (sigmoid), $f''(x)$ ( peak )  ) has this properties (fast to evaluate and smooth)

For example, [Fast Sigmoid](http://txt.arboreus.com/2013/03/29/fast-sigmoid.html) $f'(x) = x/(1+|x|)$ is not so good because it's integral $f(x)$ constains term $\log (1 \pm x)$ which is slow to evaluate, and it's derivative $f''(x) = 1/(1+|x|)^2 $ has sharp kink (derivative discontinuity) at $x=0$